# jQuery plugin child function and setTimeout

Tags: jquery, scope, settimeout

I wrote an autocomplete plugin for my website, which takes a file path and and the search data and then does a post to get results. The thing I realized is that I'm posting on every keyup of the input, and that's not good. So I thought add a timeout that would only do the search 1 second (or maybe .5 sec) after the last keyup. Unfortunately, it seems that setTimeout can't find my function, and I'm not sure why. The specific error in FireBug is "ReferenceError: search is not defined'. If I don't use the timeout, search gets called just fine. Some help figuring this out (seems like a scope issue) would be nice.

Here's the code (pruned down, there's more) that I'm trying to get working. The search function and the keyup are the important parts. Once I can get this working, I'll move the stuff just above the setTimeout into the function (assuming the variables pass ok). Obviously I have to assign setTimeout to a variable so I can overwrite it and only call it once after the time passes.

```
jQuery.fn.autocomplete = function (pathOption, sendData) {
function search() {
    console.log(this);
}

var $inputBox = $(this), onWrapper = false;
$inputBox.keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 3 && $(this).val() != $(this).data('placeholder')) {
        $.extend(sendData, { search: $(this).val() });
        $.post(SITEROOT + pathOption, sendData, function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $resultsDiv.html(data).slideDown();
            } else $resultsDiv.slideUp();
        });

        setTimeout('search', 1000);
    } else $resultsDiv.slideUp();
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to use a function reference instead of a string:

```
setTimeout(search, 1000);
```

You pretty much never want to use strings with `setTimeout()`.  If you just use a function reference like this, as long as the function is within scope of your `setTimeout()` call it will work.

---

P.S.  If you use a string which would have had to have been `setTimeout('search()', 1000)`, then the `search` function would have to have been in global scope which is generally undesirable anyway.  Avoid using strings with `setTimeout()`.  Use a javascript function reference (as in my first example) instead.

---

FYI, if you want to use `setTimeout()` to make this work, then the algorithm is generally more involved than you have illustrated.  You would need to save the timerID from `setTimeout()` so, each time you get a key event, you can cancel the previous timer and start a new one.  This will then send the post 1 second after the user pauses their typing (the usual algorithm for this type of behavior).

Comment: Ok, I haven't used setTimeout in a while, and I had first tried `setTimeout(search(), 1000)` which obviously failed, and so I thought I remembered you put it in quotes. Guess I was wrong.

And yah, I know I need to store the timerID, as I mentioned in the OP. This was just testing to get it working first, heh.